# Settings to show android app in open with list

Tags: android

I am developing an android app that has a feature to download a file when user clicks on a button. The file type can be any of Word, PDF, Excel, etc...

File download shows appropriate android app to open when the file type is Word, Excel or PDF, etc... I have a file type that is specific to customer and they developed an app to open and view this file. When the file type is this particular type download is not showing this customer app in open with list.

Customer app is already published to play store and I don't have control over it. So want to know if there is a way to fix this issue either by some setting or by adding some code in my app.

Comment: Do you want to open a specific application to display your file ? For example : open [BM application] for .pdf file type .

Comment: Are you sure that they have designed their app with an intent-filter that will allow for their app to show up in that list with files of the proper extension?  If they do not have their app setup to be used in that manner, this will not be available to you.

Comment: They are saying they have the intent-filter added to app. They asked me to create a bug. Thanks for your reponse